# Exploring the sample optixTriangle program in the Optix Engine

Tags: nvidia, optix

I am fairly new to this engine and while exploring the sample [optixTriangle program](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-optix-7/) , I made the following changes to the optixTriangle.cpp program -

- I changed some camera properties
- And I made some changes to triangle build input by changing the total no of triangles from 1 to a randomly generated 10k triangles all of which would lie in the range (-10,-10,-10) to (10,10,10)
- Changed the miss record data to { 0.7f, 0.8f, 1.0f } so that we can have a sky blue color as our background and in the `extern "C" __global__ void __closesthit__ch()` in the optixTriangle.cu I am setting the payload to a constant value of `setPayload( make_float3(0.98f, 0.360f, 0.360f) )` so that I can have a uniform color on all of my rendered triangles.

I am attaching the optixTriangle.cpp code for reference , but other than the above changes I have not changed anything else from the sample project.

```
#include <optix.h>
#include <optix_function_table_definition.h>
#include <optix_stack_size.h>
#include <optix_stubs.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include <sampleConfig.h>

#include <sutil/CUDAOutputBuffer.h>
#include <sutil/Exception.h>
#include <sutil/sutil.h>

#include "optixTriangle.h"

#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <sutil/Camera.h>
#include <sutil/Trackball.h>



template <typename T>
struct SbtRecord
{
    __align__( OPTIX_SBT_RECORD_ALIGNMENT ) char header[OPTIX_SBT_RECORD_HEADER_SIZE];
    T data;
};

typedef SbtRecord<RayGenData>     RayGenSbtRecord;
typedef SbtRecord<MissData>       MissSbtRecord;
typedef SbtRecord<HitGroupData>   HitGroupSbtRecord;


void configureCamera( sutil::Camera& cam, const uint32_t width, const uint32_t height )
{
    cam.setEye( {-5.0f, 0.0f, -25.0f} );
    cam.setLookat( {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f} );
    cam.setUp( {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f} );
    cam.setFovY( 65.0f );
    cam.setAspectRatio( (float)width / (float)height );
}


void printUsageAndExit( const char* argv0 )
{
    std::cerr << "Usage  : " << argv0 << " [options]\n";
    std::cerr << "Options: --file | -f <filename>      Specify file for image output\n";
    std::cerr << "         --help | -h                 Print this usage message\n";
    std::cerr << "         --dim=<width>x<height>      Set image dimensions; defaults to 512x384\n";
    exit( 1 );
}


static void context_log_cb( unsigned int level, const char* tag, const char* message, void* /*cbdata */)
{
    std::cerr << "[" << std::setw( 2 ) << level << "][" << std::setw( 12 ) << tag << "]: "
              << message << "\n";
}


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::string outfile;
    int         width  = 1024;
    int         height =  768;

    for( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i )
    {
        const std::string arg( argv[i] );
        if( arg == "--help" || arg == "-h" )
        {
            printUsageAndExit( argv[0] );
        }
        else if( arg == "--file" || arg == "-f" )
        {
            if( i < argc - 1 )
            {
                outfile = argv[++i];
            }
            else
            {
                printUsageAndExit( argv[0] );
            }
        }
        else if( arg.substr( 0, 6 ) == "--dim=" )
        {
            const std::string dims_arg = arg.substr( 6 );
            sutil::parseDimensions( dims_arg.c_str(), width, height );
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Unknown option '" << arg << "'\n";
            printUsageAndExit( argv[0] );
        }
    }

    try
    {
        //
        // Initialize CUDA and create OptiX context
        //
        OptixDeviceContext context = nullptr;
        {
            // Initialize CUDA
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaFree( 0 ) );

            // Initialize the OptiX API, loading all API entry points
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixInit() );

            // Specify context options
            OptixDeviceContextOptions options = {};
            options.logCallbackFunction       = &context_log_cb;
            options.logCallbackLevel          = 4;

            // Associate a CUDA context (and therefore a specific GPU) with this
            // device context
            CUcontext cuCtx = 0;  // zero means take the current context
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixDeviceContextCreate( cuCtx, &options, &context ) );
        }


        //
        // accel handling
        //
        OptixTraversableHandle gas_handle;
        CUdeviceptr            d_gas_output_buffer;
        {
            // Use default options for simplicity.  In a real use case we would want to
            // enable compaction, etc
            OptixAccelBuildOptions accel_options = {};
            accel_options.buildFlags = OPTIX_BUILD_FLAG_NONE;
            accel_options.operation  = OPTIX_BUILD_OPERATION_BUILD;
            //accel_options.acceleratorDescriptor.type = OPTIX_ACCELERATION_LBVH;

            // Triangle build input: simple list of three vertices
            std::vector<float3> vertices;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                float3 rand_point = make_float3(static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 20.0f - 10.0f,
                    static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 20.0f - 10.0f,
                    static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 20.0f - 10.0f);
                float3 v1 = rand_point - make_float3(static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX - 0.5f,
                    static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX - 0.5f,
                    static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX - 0.5f);
                float3 v2 = rand_point - make_float3(static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX - 0.5f,
                    static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX - 0.5f,
                    static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX - 0.5f);
                float3 v3 = rand_point - make_float3(static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX - 0.5f,
                    static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX - 0.5f,
                    static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX - 0.5f);
                
                vertices.push_back(v1);
                vertices.push_back(v2);
                vertices.push_back(v3);
            }

            const size_t vertices_size = sizeof( float3 )*vertices.size();
            CUdeviceptr d_vertices=0;
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMalloc( reinterpret_cast<void**>( &d_vertices ), vertices_size ) );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMemcpy(
                        reinterpret_cast<void*>( d_vertices ),
                        vertices.data(),
                        vertices_size,
                        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice
                        ) );

            // Our build input is a simple list of non-indexed triangle vertices
            const uint32_t triangle_input_flags[1] = { OPTIX_GEOMETRY_FLAG_NONE };
            OptixBuildInput triangle_input = {};
            triangle_input.type                        = OPTIX_BUILD_INPUT_TYPE_TRIANGLES;
            triangle_input.triangleArray.vertexFormat  = OPTIX_VERTEX_FORMAT_FLOAT3;
            triangle_input.triangleArray.numVertices   = static_cast<uint32_t>( vertices.size() );
            triangle_input.triangleArray.vertexBuffers = &d_vertices;
            triangle_input.triangleArray.flags         = triangle_input_flags;
            triangle_input.triangleArray.numSbtRecords = 1;

            OptixAccelBufferSizes gas_buffer_sizes;
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixAccelComputeMemoryUsage(
                        context,
                        &accel_options,
                        &triangle_input,
                        1, // Number of build inputs
                        &gas_buffer_sizes
                        ) );
            CUdeviceptr d_temp_buffer_gas;
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMalloc(
                        reinterpret_cast<void**>( &d_temp_buffer_gas ),
                        gas_buffer_sizes.tempSizeInBytes
                        ) );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMalloc(
                        reinterpret_cast<void**>( &d_gas_output_buffer ),
                        gas_buffer_sizes.outputSizeInBytes
                        ) );

            OPTIX_CHECK( optixAccelBuild(
                        context,
                        0,                  // CUDA stream
                        &accel_options,
                        &triangle_input,
                        1,                  // num build inputs
                        d_temp_buffer_gas,
                        gas_buffer_sizes.tempSizeInBytes,
                        d_gas_output_buffer,
                        gas_buffer_sizes.outputSizeInBytes,
                        &gas_handle,
                        nullptr,            // emitted property list
                        0                   // num emitted properties
                        ) );

            // We can now free the scratch space buffer used during build and the vertex
            // inputs, since they are not needed by our trivial shading method
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaFree( reinterpret_cast<void*>( d_temp_buffer_gas ) ) );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaFree( reinterpret_cast<void*>( d_vertices        ) ) );
        }

        //
        // Create module
        //
        OptixModule module = nullptr;
        OptixPipelineCompileOptions pipeline_compile_options = {};
        {
            OptixModuleCompileOptions module_compile_options = {};
#if !defined( NDEBUG )
            module_compile_options.optLevel   = OPTIX_COMPILE_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL_0;
            module_compile_options.debugLevel = OPTIX_COMPILE_DEBUG_LEVEL_FULL;
#endif

            pipeline_compile_options.usesMotionBlur        = false;
            pipeline_compile_options.traversableGraphFlags = OPTIX_TRAVERSABLE_GRAPH_FLAG_ALLOW_SINGLE_GAS;
            pipeline_compile_options.numPayloadValues      = 3;
            pipeline_compile_options.numAttributeValues    = 3;
#ifdef DEBUG // Enables debug exceptions during optix launches. This may incur significant performance cost and should only be done during development.
            pipeline_compile_options.exceptionFlags = OPTIX_EXCEPTION_FLAG_DEBUG | OPTIX_EXCEPTION_FLAG_TRACE_DEPTH | OPTIX_EXCEPTION_FLAG_STACK_OVERFLOW;
#else
            pipeline_compile_options.exceptionFlags = OPTIX_EXCEPTION_FLAG_NONE;
#endif
            pipeline_compile_options.pipelineLaunchParamsVariableName = "params";
            pipeline_compile_options.usesPrimitiveTypeFlags = OPTIX_PRIMITIVE_TYPE_FLAGS_TRIANGLE;

            size_t      inputSize  = 0;
            const char* input      = sutil::getInputData( OPTIX_SAMPLE_NAME, OPTIX_SAMPLE_DIR, "optixTriangle.cu", inputSize );

            OPTIX_CHECK_LOG( optixModuleCreateFromPTX(
                        context,
                        &module_compile_options,
                        &pipeline_compile_options,
                        input,
                        inputSize,
                        LOG, &LOG_SIZE,
                        &module
                        ) );
        }

        //
        // Create program groups
        //
        OptixProgramGroup raygen_prog_group   = nullptr;
        OptixProgramGroup miss_prog_group     = nullptr;
        OptixProgramGroup hitgroup_prog_group = nullptr;
        {
            OptixProgramGroupOptions program_group_options   = {}; // Initialize to zeros

            OptixProgramGroupDesc raygen_prog_group_desc    = {}; //
            raygen_prog_group_desc.kind                     = OPTIX_PROGRAM_GROUP_KIND_RAYGEN;
            raygen_prog_group_desc.raygen.module            = module;
            raygen_prog_group_desc.raygen.entryFunctionName = "__raygen__rg";
            OPTIX_CHECK_LOG( optixProgramGroupCreate(
                        context,
                        &raygen_prog_group_desc,
                        1,   // num program groups
                        &program_group_options,
                        LOG, &LOG_SIZE,
                        &raygen_prog_group
                        ) );

            OptixProgramGroupDesc miss_prog_group_desc  = {};
            miss_prog_group_desc.kind                   = OPTIX_PROGRAM_GROUP_KIND_MISS;
            miss_prog_group_desc.miss.module            = module;
            miss_prog_group_desc.miss.entryFunctionName = "__miss__ms";
            OPTIX_CHECK_LOG( optixProgramGroupCreate(
                        context,
                        &miss_prog_group_desc,
                        1,   // num program groups
                        &program_group_options,
                        LOG, &LOG_SIZE,
                        &miss_prog_group
                        ) );

            OptixProgramGroupDesc hitgroup_prog_group_desc = {};
            hitgroup_prog_group_desc.kind                         = OPTIX_PROGRAM_GROUP_KIND_HITGROUP;
            hitgroup_prog_group_desc.hitgroup.moduleCH            = module;
            hitgroup_prog_group_desc.hitgroup.entryFunctionNameCH = "__closesthit__ch";
            OPTIX_CHECK_LOG( optixProgramGroupCreate(
                        context,
                        &hitgroup_prog_group_desc,
                        1,   // num program groups
                        &program_group_options,
                        LOG, &LOG_SIZE,
                        &hitgroup_prog_group
                        ) );
        }

        //
        // Link pipeline
        //
        OptixPipeline pipeline = nullptr;
        {
            const uint32_t    max_trace_depth = 1;
            OptixProgramGroup program_groups[] = { raygen_prog_group, miss_prog_group, hitgroup_prog_group };

            OptixPipelineLinkOptions pipeline_link_options = {};
            pipeline_link_options.maxTraceDepth          = max_trace_depth;
            pipeline_link_options.debugLevel             = OPTIX_COMPILE_DEBUG_LEVEL_FULL;

            OPTIX_CHECK_LOG( optixPipelineCreate(
                        context,
                        &pipeline_compile_options,
                        &pipeline_link_options,
                        program_groups,
                        sizeof( program_groups ) / sizeof( program_groups[0] ),
                        LOG, &LOG_SIZE,
                        &pipeline
                        ) );

            OptixStackSizes stack_sizes = {};
            for( auto& prog_group : program_groups )
            {
                OPTIX_CHECK( optixUtilAccumulateStackSizes( prog_group, &stack_sizes ) );
            }

            uint32_t direct_callable_stack_size_from_traversal;
            uint32_t direct_callable_stack_size_from_state;
            uint32_t continuation_stack_size;
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixUtilComputeStackSizes( &stack_sizes, max_trace_depth,
                                                     0,  // maxCCDepth
                                                     0,  // maxDCDEpth
                                                     &direct_callable_stack_size_from_traversal,
                                                     &direct_callable_stack_size_from_state, &continuation_stack_size ) );
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixPipelineSetStackSize( pipeline, direct_callable_stack_size_from_traversal,
                                                    direct_callable_stack_size_from_state, continuation_stack_size,
                                                    1  // maxTraversableDepth
                                                    ) );
        }

        //
        // Set up shader binding table
        //
        OptixShaderBindingTable sbt = {};
        {
            CUdeviceptr  raygen_record;
            const size_t raygen_record_size = sizeof( RayGenSbtRecord );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMalloc( reinterpret_cast<void**>( &raygen_record ), raygen_record_size ) );
            RayGenSbtRecord rg_sbt;
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixSbtRecordPackHeader( raygen_prog_group, &rg_sbt ) );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMemcpy(
                        reinterpret_cast<void*>( raygen_record ),
                        &rg_sbt,
                        raygen_record_size,
                        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice
                        ) );

            CUdeviceptr miss_record;
            size_t      miss_record_size = sizeof( MissSbtRecord );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMalloc( reinterpret_cast<void**>( &miss_record ), miss_record_size ) );
            MissSbtRecord ms_sbt;
            ms_sbt.data = { 0.7f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixSbtRecordPackHeader( miss_prog_group, &ms_sbt ) );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMemcpy(
                        reinterpret_cast<void*>( miss_record ),
                        &ms_sbt,
                        miss_record_size,
                        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice
                        ) );

            CUdeviceptr hitgroup_record;
            size_t      hitgroup_record_size = sizeof( HitGroupSbtRecord );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMalloc( reinterpret_cast<void**>( &hitgroup_record ), hitgroup_record_size ) );
            HitGroupSbtRecord hg_sbt;
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixSbtRecordPackHeader( hitgroup_prog_group, &hg_sbt ) );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMemcpy(
                        reinterpret_cast<void*>( hitgroup_record ),
                        &hg_sbt,
                        hitgroup_record_size,
                        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice
                        ) );

            sbt.raygenRecord                = raygen_record;
            sbt.missRecordBase              = miss_record;
            sbt.missRecordStrideInBytes     = sizeof( MissSbtRecord );
            sbt.missRecordCount             = 1;
            sbt.hitgroupRecordBase          = hitgroup_record;
            sbt.hitgroupRecordStrideInBytes = sizeof( HitGroupSbtRecord );
            sbt.hitgroupRecordCount         = 1;
        }

        sutil::CUDAOutputBuffer<uchar4> output_buffer( sutil::CUDAOutputBufferType::CUDA_DEVICE, width, height );

        //
        // launch
        //
        {
            CUstream stream;
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaStreamCreate( &stream ) );

            sutil::Camera cam;
            configureCamera( cam, width, height );

            Params params;
            params.image        = output_buffer.map();
            params.image_width  = width;
            params.image_height = height;
            params.handle       = gas_handle;
            params.cam_eye      = cam.eye();
            cam.UVWFrame( params.cam_u, params.cam_v, params.cam_w );

            CUdeviceptr d_param;
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMalloc( reinterpret_cast<void**>( &d_param ), sizeof( Params ) ) );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaMemcpy(
                        reinterpret_cast<void*>( d_param ),
                        &params, sizeof( params ),
                        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice
                        ) );

            OPTIX_CHECK( optixLaunch( pipeline, stream, d_param, sizeof( Params ), &sbt, width, height, /*depth=*/1 ) );
            CUDA_SYNC_CHECK();

            output_buffer.unmap();
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaFree( reinterpret_cast<void*>( d_param ) ) );
        }

        //
        // Display results
        //
        {
            sutil::ImageBuffer buffer;
            buffer.data         = output_buffer.getHostPointer();
            buffer.width        = width;
            buffer.height       = height;
            buffer.pixel_format = sutil::BufferImageFormat::UNSIGNED_BYTE4;
            if( outfile.empty() )
                sutil::displayBufferWindow( argv[0], buffer );
            else
                sutil::saveImage( outfile.c_str(), buffer, false );
        }

        //
        // Cleanup
        //
        {
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaFree( reinterpret_cast<void*>( sbt.raygenRecord       ) ) );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaFree( reinterpret_cast<void*>( sbt.missRecordBase     ) ) );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaFree( reinterpret_cast<void*>( sbt.hitgroupRecordBase ) ) );
            CUDA_CHECK( cudaFree( reinterpret_cast<void*>( d_gas_output_buffer    ) ) );

            OPTIX_CHECK( optixPipelineDestroy( pipeline ) );
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixProgramGroupDestroy( hitgroup_prog_group ) );
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixProgramGroupDestroy( miss_prog_group ) );
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixProgramGroupDestroy( raygen_prog_group ) );
            OPTIX_CHECK( optixModuleDestroy( module ) );

            OPTIX_CHECK( optixDeviceContextDestroy( context ) );
        }
    }
    catch( std::exception& e )
    {
        std::cerr << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following output -
[image]

Now I wanted to make some more changes but have no idea how to proceed further -

- I am not sure which acceleration structure this program is using, I checked the accel options but didnt find anything concrete. I wanted to use a BVH structure so what changes should I make in the code which would warantee that I am using a BVH acceleration structure.
- I wanted to change the samples pex pixel , from the output I would assume that by default the samples per pixel for the program is very low and I wanted to set the samples per pixel to 64
- Even after I change the max trace depth to a higher no other than 1, I get no visible changes , I was expecting shadows/depth but I am getting the same output each and every time.

  ````
        // Link pipeline
        //
        OptixPipeline pipeline = nullptr;
        {
            const uint32_t    max_trace_depth = 10;
            OptixProgramGroup program_groups[] = { raygen_prog_group, miss_prog_group, hitgroup_prog_group }; ```
  ````

I had built a custom ray tracer a while back and with the above variables I was expecting an output similar to this -
[image]

But in the output that I got from my optix program , I see no depth and no shadows. I know i might be missing a lot of points but as I said I am fairly new to this engine and finding it very difficult to navigate around.